# nullpointerexception error I do now know how to fix

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device

where is error? how can I fix it? layout is true error in 24th line that

```
kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

here is my all codes

```
public class oyuncuAdlariActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button kaleciKayit;
Button oyuncuKayit;
EditText isimGiris;
String isimGirisString;
int kaleciSayisi = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_oyuncu_adlari);
    kaleciKayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kaleciButton);
    oyuncuKayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oyuncuButton);
    isimGiris = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isimGir);
    kaleciKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            kaleciSayisi++;
            isimGirisString = isimGiris.getText().toString();
            if (isimGirisString.isEmpty()){
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.isimBos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
            }
            else if (kaleciSayisi >2)
                kaleciKayit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will recommend setting the objects in a class to private. I think the problem is that maybe you are assigning the id of the wrong widget? check the FindViewByID again.

The other 3 possibilities that I can think about are-

1. The problem is in the first activity(In this case I ask you to post here the content of the first activity)
2. The setContentView method points at a wrong XML file.
3. Your AVD ran out of memory and you need to add more to it in the AVD Manager tool.

Comment: Thank you I will try.

Comment: I cant find the problem and solution but added first activity codes

Comment: yeah I added ram and storage memory still same
When activity was empty there was no error

Answer (score 0):

Change MainActivity to this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button devamButton;
EditText takim1, takim2;
String takimTextA;
String takimTextB;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    devamButton = findViewById(R.id.devamButton);
    takim1 = findViewById(R.id.takimB);
    takim2 = findViewById(R.id.takimA);
    devamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            takimTextA = takim1.getText().toString();
            takimTextB = takim2.getText().toString();
            if (takimTextA.equals(takimTextB)) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getString(takimAyniOlmaz), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
            } else if (takimTextA.isEmpty() || takimTextB.isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.takimBosBirakma), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();
            } else {
                activityGecis1(v);
            }
        }
    });
}
private void activityGecis1(View v) {
       Intent gecis1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), oyuncuAdlariActivity.class);
     startActivity(gecis1);
}
```

Since you are calling inside onclicklistener maybe this in intent may point to that functions class.